# MVVM Light binding to RIA IEnumerable

Tags: data-binding, linq-to-entities, ienumerable, ria, mvvm-light

**Problem:**  How to bind a RIA IEnumerable with a nested IEnumberable to Silverlight controls using MVVM Light and Blend?

**Setup:**  I have setup RIA services to work with a simple Entity Framework model that has two entities Category and Activity; where each Category can include many Activities.
The domain service has a function GetCategoriesWithActivities() that returns:

```
return this.ObjectContext.Categories.Include("Activities");
```

The Model uses the DataContext.Load to execute the query and returns a LoadOperation which has an Entities property that is an IEnumberable.  Since the query Includes Activities there is also a nested IEnumerable.  Using Visual Studio’s debugger I can see that the data is being returned in the IEnumerable.

My ViewModel exposes the returned IEnumerable as a public property.  Using MVVM Light the ViewModel is set as the Model’s DataContext.

When I try to databind to the IEnuberable the members of Category are not available not to mention the members of the nested Activities.

**Question:**  What data type should my ViewModel expose so that I can bind to the Categories and the nested Activities?  How do I convert the IEnumerable to that type?  I want to use the original RIA Category and Activity objects so the change tracking will work.

PS: I forgot to mention that my ultimate goal is to bind the Categories and Activities IEnumerables to the Accordion control.

Answer (score 0):

I convert my iEnumerables to ObservableCollections or ICollections in the OnLoadOperationCompleted callback.

```
public void onQuestionsLoaded(LoadOperation<Questions> lo)
        {
            if (!lo.HasError)
            {
                ICollection<Questions> q = new ObservableCollection<Questions>(lo.Entities);
                var action = (Action<ICollection<Questions>>)lo.UserState;
                action.Invoke(q);
            }
            else
```